# php or unix command add watermark on pdf pages

Tags: php, unix

how with php or unix command add watermark on (existing) pdf pages?

Now i use pdftk, but with this command i can't change watermark position.
I need watermark in bottom page.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use pdftk to add the watermark/stamp. You should just create a PDF with your watermark/stamp **in the correct position** first, and then use either the [background](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-background) or [stamp](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-stamp) to combine it with your PDF.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know pdf page width and height. Each page can be different

Comment: Then you will have to find a way to determine the dimensions of every page first, create the "watermark" pdf dynamically based on these dimensions (per page) and still use pdftk - with multibackground/multistamp.